# access to global variables in lua

Tags: lua, global-variables, local-variables

I have a Lua code below :

```
a, b = 1, 10
if a<b then
    print(a)
    local a
    print(a)
end
print(a, b)
```

Just a small question : 
first of all, I created a global variable a = 1;

 then in the **then** block I use the **global variable a** to print it;
 and then I declared a **local variable a** that is not initialized (**thus it gets the value nil**)
Then my question comes : how could I get access to the **global variable a** after having created the **local variable a** in the **then block**, is that possible ? If so, please give me an answer :)

Comment: that sounds very confusing and error prone.

Comment: @Piglet Look at the answer, plz. This question is logical so that someone can answer.

Comment: not your question. I mean reusing variable names that way. its dangerous and the code becomes hard to read

Comment: @Piglet I see, thx for the advice :)

Comment: It kinda makes sense once you've finished the code and want to minimize it as much as possible to reuse variable names like this, there's only so many letters and words out there and if lua let's us reuse some of them. Great! Whilst you're testing and doing work like this though I recommend using more verbose variable names to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `_ENV.a` to access the global variable after using the same name for a local one!

Note, Lua versions 5.1 and below use `_G`

Edit, Just tested this:

```
a, b = 1, 10
if a<b then
    local a = 12
    print(a) -- Will print 12
    print(_ENV.a) -- Will print 1
end
print(a, b) -- Will print 1 10
```

And it worked fine, gave me the desired output referencing _ENV.a

Comment: @Kershrew I have another question : how could I do the same thing if I add **local to the first line variable a** ? Is that possible ? In this case, the first a will be local to the whole chunk (**but it cannot be accessed via _ENV.a nor _G.a in the then block**) and the second a is always local to the **then block**

Comment: @SWIIWII local makes the variable set within the current scope. _ENV will always access the top level global a that you set and you can use locals to reuse that variable name further down the line. 
Although honestly I don't know why you don't stop confusing yourself and use different names for the variables. :)

Comment: @Kershrew I find this code in the official lua tutorial and I just want to know all the usage of the local and global variables in all possible cases, it's just about curiosity :) I am of course aware that using the same name for local and global variables is quite awkward :)